# How to access the user profile in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm storing some additional per-user information using the [`AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users).

We can access the user in a Django template using `{{ request.user }}` but how do we access fields in the profile since the profile is only accessible via a function `user.get_profile()` ?

Is it really required to explicitly pass the profile into the template every time?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Use `{{ request.user.get_profile.whatever }}`. Django's templating language automatically calls things that are callable - in this case, the `.get_profile()` method.

Comment: See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables The rules are very cool.

Comment: This is deprecated in Django 1.5 and up and does not work in Django 1.7 and up. See Sacha Rau's answer for how to do this in modern Django.

Answer (score 28):

Not sure why it's different for me, but I need to use {{user}} rather than {{request.user}}.

Comment: The docs say (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates) that you can access the user simply by {{user}}, as you say.

Comment: The real reason for using {{user}} and not {{request.user}} is because you do not include the template context processor for request. [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request)

Comment: The link is slightly different for Django 1.10, but idea is the same, the `django.template.context_processors.request` inserts the `request` in template, while the `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` inserts `user` in context. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible to access profile from template using 
   request.user.get_profile

However there is a small **caveat**: not all users will have profiles, which was in my case with admin users. So calling directly
   `{{ request.user.get_profile.whatever }}` from the template will cause an error in such cases.

If you are sure all your users always have profiles it is safe to call from template, otherwise call `get_profile()` from within try-except block in your view and pass it to the template.

Comment: This answer is misleading - I haven't tested `{{ request.user.get_profile.whatever }}`, but `{{ request.user.get_profile }}` will work and can be used to check whether a profile exists or not in current versions. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#how-invalid-variables-are-handled . There is a note that that will change in the development version, though, see the paragraph above the one I linked to.

Comment: @tkolar, what exactly is misleading here? if user doesn't have a profile and you are calling get_profile.something that will cause an error.

Answer (score 5):

If it helps anyone, I used the followings in my template:

Username: `{{ user.username }}`

User Full name: `{{ user.get_full_name }}`

User Group: `{{ user.groups.all.0 }}`

Email: `{{ user.email }}`

Session Started at: `{{ user.last_login }}`

**A sample result is like this:**

> User: auditor ezio
>
> User Group: auditGroup
>
> Username: testUser03
>
> Email: testuser03@auditor.com
>
> Session Started at- April 16, 2018, 9:38 p.m.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Django > 1.5 you can no longer use `get_profile`.

If you have a legacy app, you should remove `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myapp.profile'` from your `settings.py`.

If you use `models.OneToOneField(User)` in your Profile class, you can simply use

```
{{ request.user.profile.whatever }}
```

in your Django template

Comment: @AlexStewart you mean we no longer need the `request` keyboard in the front?

Answer (score 1):

Working !

In your profile model provide related_name

```
user = models.OneToOneField(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="user_profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then in template use. Here company_name is field in profile table

```
{{ request.user.user_profile.company_name }}
```