# django - relations between models

Tags: django, django-models, relational-database

i have two model which are Post and Profile. i am keepin blog datas which are title,body,owner,slug etc in Post. and keepin' user profile settings which are slogan,email,website etc. in Profile

in my index.html page i display user profile infos and post lists in same page. so ;
i need to connect these two models each other. when someone goes to 127.0.0.1/blog/username  (with or without login) all the data which are belong to user named 'username' must be there.

here is my models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    slogan = models.TextField(blank=True)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length = 100,blank=True)
    web_site = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 100,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slogan


class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body = models.TextField()
    bodyPreview = models.TextField() #preview için body alanı
    titlePreview = models.CharField(max_length=100) # preview için title alanı
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title' ,unique=True)
    posted = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    isdraft = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_blog_post',None,{'postslug':self.slug})
```

and my index view :

```
def index(request,username):
    post_list = Post.objects.filter(owner__username=username).filter(isdraft=False).order_by("-posted")
    p_index = Paginator(post_list,3) #anasayfa için pagination.[her sayfada 3 post]
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        indexPag = p_index.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        indexPag = p_index.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        indexPag = p_index.page(p_index.num_pages)

    ## i need to get user's profile datas here. ??

    return render_to_response('index.html',
                             {'post_list':post_list,'p_index':indexPag,'profile':query},
                             context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Where is the FK to `User` from `Profile`?

Comment: and after FK ; how should i reach Profile Model's fields from view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change your Profile model and add a OneToOne relationship to the User model(for more info see [here](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/)):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...

class Posts(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

and then in your views you can do:

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
post_list = Post.objects.filter(author=user).filter(isdraft=False).order_by("-posted") 

return render_to_response('index.html', 
                           {'post_list': post_list, 'user': user, ...}, ...)
```

And then in your template you are able to access the user's profile.More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422140/how-to-access-the-user-profile-in-a-django-template)
e.g `{{user.get_profile.slogan}}`

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

```
def index(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'user':user})
```

In your template:

```
{{ user.post_set }}
```

and You will receive list of posts of current user.

Comment: there is no trouble about gettin' post list. i need to get profile settings which belongs to user.

Answer (score 0):

The *most natural* way to achieve that is to **add** a OneToOne relation between your **Profile** model and the django's **User** model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # More fields

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # More fields
```

This way, you can access the profile data through a User object. Would be something like this:

```
user = User.objecets.get(username=username)
profile = user.profile
```

More info about this, you can read the django model fields documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield)
and you can also see [this cool answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870537/whats-the-difference-between-django-onetoonefield-and-foreignkey) about the diference between the ForeignKey with unique=True and the OneToOneField

I hope this helps