# Get user information in django templates

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-registration

What's the best way to get user information from a django template?

For example, if I just want to:

1. If the user is logged in, display "Welcome [username]"
2. Otherwise, display the login button.

I'm using django-registration/authentication

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the user profile in a Django template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422140/how-to-access-the-user-profile-in-a-django-template)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

An alternate method for current Django versions:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.get_username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Note:

- Use `request.user.get_username()` in views & `user.get_username` in templates. Preferred over referring `username` attribute directly. [Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_username)
- This template context variable is available if a RequestContext is used.
- `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` is enabled by default & contains the variable user
- You do NOT need to enable `django.core.context_processors.request` template context processor.

Source : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates

Answer (score 46):

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}Welcome '{{ request.user.username }}'
{% else %}<a href="{% url django.contrib.auth.login %}">Login</a>{% endif %}
```

and make sure you have the `request` template context processor installed in your `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 40):

As per the question title, the following may come handy to someone.  used the followings in my template:

**Username**: `{{ user.username }}`

**User Full name**: `{{ user.get_full_name }}`

**User Group**: `{{ user.groups.all.0 }}`

**Email**: `{{ user.email }}`

**Session Started at**: `{{ user.last_login }}`

Thanks :)

Comment: I was also intentionally going with {{ user.username }}, but as @user mentioned in the accepted answer, it has some drawbacks and {{ user.get_username }} should be preferred using the user instance.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, First, if your fields changed their name, you must overwrite the functions (get_full_name(), get_short_name(), etc), in this way:

```
def get_full_name(self):
    return self.names + ' ' + self.lastnames

def get_short_name(self):
    return self.names
```

In the template, you can show it this way

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<strong>{{ user.get_short_name }}</strong>
{% endif %}
```

these are the methods in authentication https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/

Answer (score 0):

The following is a full working solution that takes also translations into consideration:

`template.html`:

```
{% blocktrans %}Welcome {{ USER_NAME }}!{% endblocktrans %}
```

`context_processors.py`:

```
def template_constants(request):
    return {
        'USER_NAME': '' if request.user.is_anonymous else request.user.first_name,
        # other values here...
    }
```

Remind to set your custom context_processors correctly in the `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # ...
                'your_app.context_processors.template_constants',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And this is what you get in the `django.po`:

```
#: templates/home.html:11
#, python-format
msgid "Hi %(USER_NAME)s!"
msgstr "..."
```

A good practice is to keep the logic outside the templates: for this purpose you can easily customize the username displayed directly in the `context_processors.py`.