# How get current user in a template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

How can i get the current user in a django template tags? (request object is not accessible)
Or how can i access to request object?

Comment: You can create it as context processor than creating template tags and call it always in a template. In context processor you can get the user without calling the function in a template always.

Comment: Really complicated for a one liner template tag.. Is really django so unhandly?

Comment: Or try to put this in your template {{user.username}}

Comment: What do you want to show then? If it's not useful then your question is incomplete. If you really want help be nice, be more specific and give sample.

Comment: The question is pretty clear, he wants to access the current user in a template tag

Comment: @msc I give him sample on how to access current user but he replied it's not really he really want. Then what he really want? I understand what his question above.

Comment: He wants to either access the current user object in a template tag, or the request object in a template tag. Not in a context processor, or as a variable in the template.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to access the current user in a template tag, you must pass it as a parameter in the templates, like so:

```
{% my_template_tag user %}
```

Then make sure your template tag accepts this extra parameter. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag) on this topic. You should also check out [simple tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags).

Answer (score 19):

The user is always attached to the request, in your templates you can do the following:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% endif %}
```

You don't have to specify "request" to access its content

**UPDATE:**

Be aware: `is_authenticated()` always return `True` for logged user (`User` objects), but returns `False` for `AnonymousUser` (guest users). Read here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/

Comment: `user.is_authenticated` always returns true so it's basically useless.

Comment: no! It always return true for User (logged ones), but returns false for AnonymousUser, so is not useless! Read here carefully: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/

Answer (score 7):

This question was already [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13713164/2142093):

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p> Welcome '{{ user.username }}'</p>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url django.contrib.auth.login %}">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

and make sure you have the request template context processor installed in your settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
...
'django.core.context_processors.request',
...
)
```

Note:

- Use `request.user.get_username()` in views & `user.get_username` in
  templates. Preferred over referring username attribute directly.
  [Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_username)
- This template context variable is available if a RequestContext is used.
- django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth is enabled by default & contains the variable user
- You do NOT need to enable django.core.context_processors.request template context processor.

Source : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have a profile page of every registered user, and you only want to show the edit link to the owner of the profile page (i.e., if the current user is accessing his/her profile page, the user can see the edit button, but the user can't see the edit button on other user's profile page.
In your **html** file:

```
<h2>Profile of {{ object.username }}</h2>
{% if object.username == user.username %}
    <a href="{% url 'profile_update' object.pk %}">Edit</a>
{% endif %}
```

Then your **urls.py**  file should contain:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ProfileUpdateView
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<int:pk>/profile/update', ProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name = 'profile_update'),
    ...
]
```

considering you have appropriate `ProfileUpdateView` and appropriate model