# How to get the username of the logged-in user in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

How can I get information about the logged-in user in a Django application?

For example:

I need to know the username of the logged-in user to say who posted a Review:

```
<form id='formulario' method='POST' action=''>
    <h2>Publica tu tuit, {{ usuario.username.title }} </h2>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{formulario.as_p}}
    <p><input type='submit' value='Confirmar' /></p>
</form>
```

In `usuario.username.title` I get the username, but in the template, I need to get that information from the view.

Comment: what is `usario` is it the user object or the userprofile ?

Comment: Yes, is the profile, but i need to get the username in the view to save in the model. =)

Comment: ok. .check the answer. that is how you access the username from the view

Answer (score 126):

You can use the request object to find the logged in user

```
def my_view(request):
    username = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        username = request.user.username
```

According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.10/

In version Django 2.0 the syntax has changed to

```
request.user.is_authenticated
```

Comment: if request.user.is_authenticated():
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

can you help on it
django 3.2

Answer (score 50):

`request.user.get_username()` or `request.user.username`, former is preferred.

[Django docs say:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_username)

> Since the User model can be swapped
>   out, you should use this method instead of referencing the username
>   attribute directly.

P.S. For templates, use `{{ user.get_username }}`

Answer (score 13):

'**request.user**' has the logged in user.
'**request.user.username**' will return username of logged in user.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: it will return User object. you can get some user properties from this object.

Answer (score 12):

For classed based views use `self.request.user.id`

Comment: Request param on method, i just use request.user.id for example

Answer (score 8):

You can use this to get the logged-in user's username :-

Just write this in template.

```
{{ request.user.username }}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using the old way of writting views, in the way of Function-Based-Views...

in your view, you are creating  a new variable called `usuario` to save the request.user probably...

but if you returning to the `Template` a `context_instance`, passing the value of the Context of the request, you will get the logged user, just by accessing the `request`.

```
// In your views file
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
def your_view(request):
    data = {
        'formulario': Formulario()
        # ...
    }
    return render_to_response('your_template.html',
        data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


// In your template
<form id='formulario' method='POST' action=''>
    <h2>Publica tu tuit, {{ request.user.username.title }} </h2>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formulario.as_p }}
    <p><input type='submit' value='Confirmar' /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: To use this, you must have  the `request template context processor` installed in your `settings.py`. [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713077/get-user-information-in-django-templates)

Comment: Is 'Function-Based-Views...' an old way of writing views?

Comment: Hi @Gathide, yea. If you see this answer is from 2013... back then the Class-based views weren't really a thing, nowadays the Request processor is pretty standard on templates and you can just use `{{ request.user.username }}`. I recommend you reading this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Answer (score 2):

`request.user.get_username()` will return a string of the users email.

`request.user.username` will return a method.

Answer (score 2):

in this way you can check is user is logged in or not If yes for example go to profile if not back to login page

```
def profile(request):
    try:
        if request.user.username in User:
            return render(request, "profile.html", {'username': request.user.username})
    except:
        return redirect("/accounts/login")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpRequest.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) and [get_user(request)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#utility-functions) to get the username of the logged-in user in Django Views as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import get_user # Here

def test(request):
    print(request.user.username) # John
    print(get_user(request).username) # John
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

And, you can get the username of the logged-in user in Django Templates as shown below:

```
{% "index.html" %}

{{ user }} {% John %}
{{ user.username }} {% John %}
{{ user.get_username }} {% John %}
```

Answer (score -1):

For template, you can use

```
{% firstof request.user.get_full_name request.user.username %}
```

firstof will return the first one if not null else the second one