# Django - handle user information

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

Say I have a login procedure in my website and that I login successfully.

After the user credential's successful authentication, I redirect to some page like

```
url(r'^account/profile/$',views.profile,name="profile")
```

Now my question is: if there are no arguments to the urlconf, how can I access the logged user's information in a view or template? (e.g. how can I know the username of that user in my template?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the username of the logged-in user in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906515/how-can-i-get-the-username-of-the-logged-in-user-in-django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the current User in a view with `request.user`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the logged user using `{{user.username}}`

And if you want to send the user data to template,

```
def profile(request, ):
   user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
   return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user_info': user})
```

profile.html:

```
{{ user_info }}
```

Note: user_info is current user instance. You can handle user data with this instance.

Comment: Is that feature implicit across django? That is, how would I call some of the currently logged user's methods in the view?

Comment: yes this future is implicit. you can find authenticated user also like `{{ user.is_authenticated }}`