# How to user Email modelform should be initialised with current user's mail address in django

Tags: python, django, email

How to initialize the email form with from_email address which is the current user's email address in django. I am using post-office application and wish to populate the from email address. How can the initial value be set as:

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.base_fields['from_email'].initial = 'hi@s.com'
       super(EmailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

But the email id should vary dynamically. The request object is available in the changelist_view for the EmailAdmin and not in the ModelForm to take advantage of.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a similar question:  [How can I get the username of the logged-in user in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906515/how-can-i-get-the-username-of-the-logged-in-user-in-django)

For your case, retrieve the user email address, and pass that in the request context to the template. You don't need to subclass anything

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        email = request.user.email
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/469072/joel-goldstick I am using the django-postoffice application where I use the Email model. I know how to get the current user mail address in the view but not for form init

Comment: I want something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841502/how-to-use-the-request-in-I a-modelform-in-django?answertab=oldest#tab-top