# In Django, how do I generate a welcome message for the user?

Tags: python, html, css, django

Something like:

```
Welcome {user that is logged in}!
```

It should appear when the user logs in.
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get user information in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713077/get-user-information-in-django-templates)

Comment: Please help to add some details to your question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You gotta create your own login view and then you can use messages to display the welcome message like:

```
from django.contrib import messages    
messages.success(request, gettext("Login successfully !"))
# gettext is for the translation,  you don't need it
```