# How to subtract from a Django model?

Tags: python, django, math

I am trying to add and subtract 1 from the value of a Django model's IntegerField and display it on the webpage, depending on when a button is clicked.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    following = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="followers", symmetrical=False)
    following_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

In views.py:

To add: `following_num = page_visitor.following_num +1`

To subtract: `following_num = page_visitor.following_num -1`

This is displaying in the html where the number should be displaying:

`<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000022868D735E0>`

entire view:

```
def username(request, user):
    #get user
    user = get_object_or_404(User.objects, username=user)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-date_and_time')
    page_visitor = get_object_or_404(User.objects, username=request.user)

    if user == request.user:
        followButton = False
    else:
        followButton = True

    if request.method == "POST":
        if "follow" in request.POST:
            request.user.following.add(user)
            following_num = page_visitor.following_num +1
            #following_num = F('User.following_num') + 1

        elif "unfollow" in request.POST:
            request.user.following.remove(user)
            following_num = page_visitor.following_num -1
            #following_num = F('User.following_num') - 1

    followers_num = page_visitor.following_num
    following_num = User.following_num
    return render(request, "network/username.html",{
        "user": user,
        "posts": posts,
        "followButton": followButton,
        "followers": followers_num,
        "following": following_num
    })
```

html

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ user }}</h1>
    <h4>Followers:{{ followers }}</h4>
    <h4>Following:{{ following }}</h4>
    <!--follow/unfollow button-->
    {% if followButton == True %}
    <form action = "{% url 'username' user %}" method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if user not in request.user.following.all %}
            <input type="submit" value="Follow" name="follow">
        {% else %}
            <input type="submit" value="Unfollow" name="unfollow">
        {% endif %}
    </form>
    {% endif %}
    

    <!--displays all the posts-->
    {% for post in posts %}
            <div class = "individual_posts">
                <a href="{% url 'username' post.user %}"><h5 class = "post_user">{{ post.user }}</h5></a>
                <h6 id = "post_itself">{{ post.post }}</h6>
                <h6 class = "post_elements">{{ post.date_and_time }}</h6>
                <h6 class = "post_elements">{{ post.likes }} Likes</h6>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Share the full view...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I added the entire view.

Comment: Share the html where you are attempting to display the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you reference the class (model) and not the object (instance)

> following_num = **U**ser.following_num

as you alredy passed your user object to the template you can also access the attributes directly
`{{user.following_num }} {{request.user.following_num }}`

but you better rename the passed user variable to avoid confusion / errors

[Get user information in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713077/get-user-information-in-django-templates)

Answer (score 0):

Without the html that is supposed to display the number I cant tell why it is displaying that, but if you intend to change the following count then you need to call `page_visitor.save()` after changing a property of page_visitor in order for it to save the new property's value in the database

Comment: Hendrick, I added ```page_visitor.save()``` and nothing changed. I also added the html.