# how to use: from __future__ import division with django

Tags: django, django-templates

i'm trying to use `__future__ import division` with django for my operation but it won't work in my views.py.

under django shell it great same with python shell:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> result = 37 / 3
>>> result
12.333333333333334
>>>
```

The same thing in django views.py don't works when i try to use it.

```
error message: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'instancemethod'
```

views.py :

```
from __future__ import division

def show_product(request, product_slug, template_name="product.html"):
    review_total_final = decimal.Decimal('0.0')
    review_total = 0
    product_count = product_reviews.count # the number of product rated occurences
    if product_count == 0:
        return review_total_final
    else:
        for product_torate in product_reviews:
            review_total += product_torate.rating
            review_total_final = review_total / product_count
            return review_total_final
    return review_total_final
```

models.py:

```
class ProductReview(models.Model):
    RATINGS =((5,5),.....,)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=5, choices=RATINGS)
    content = models.TextField()
```

product_reviews is a queryset.

Any help !!!

Comment: can you show the usage in your views.py ?

Comment: views.py  def show_product(request, product_slug, template_name="product.html"): review_total_final = decimal.Decimal('0.0')
 review_total = 0
 product_count = product_reviews.count # the number of product rated occurences
 if product_count == 0:
  
  return review_total_final
 else:
  for product_torate in product_reviews:
   review_total += product_torate.rating
  review_total_final = review_total / product_count
  #review_total_final= Ratestar.objects.filter(rate__gte = F(review_total) / F(product_count))  
  return review_total_final
 return review_total_final

Comment: There's, um, a lot wrong. .count is probably supposed to be .count(), maybe same with .rating and .rating(), but the indentation is really funky, can't really tell.

Comment: it's count not count() , try it before saying lot wrong. ok

Comment: Could you please show your product_review model? What is the type of `rating` field?

Comment: i want this  AdamKG  to answer now if he really know django

Comment: Obviously, count is a method and you should call it: `product_count = product_reviews.count()`.

Comment: i understand people filling about this count() but nothing wrong with it. product_count = product_reviews.count when i format the {{product_count}} on the template i get the exact value. but other thing with count(). the matter is not there.

Comment: No, this is the problem -- Django's template system will call the method if you pass in the method object instead of calling it, but Python won't.

Comment: ok, i will try to figure out , thanks Fredrik

Comment: @ali2005 Wow. I try not to be an asshole, but it just so happens that function-call parens in templates vs python code [is my highest-rated answer evar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/422153/16361)...

Comment: avoiding violent answer is better and respectfull

Comment: So I'm not sure what you're saying here, Adam -- was I supposed to know about a 4-year old answer so I could link to it?  I just signed up...

Answer (score 2):

`from __future__ import division` has nothing to do this with this; you're trying to divide a value by the method itself, instead of calling the method first to get a proper operand.  Compare and contrast:

```
>>> class X(object):
...   def count(self):
...     return 1
... 
>>> x = X()
>>> 1 / x.count
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'instancemethod'
>>> 1 / x.count()
1
```