# 'user' not available in template django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am using a custom user model with builtin and custom authentication backends. the default for username-password login and the custom one for uid based login The login is working fine but the 'user' (Other than superuser) is not available in the template.Nor is the last_login getting updated in database. Here is my code

backend.py

```
from support.models import CustomUser

class UsernameIdModelBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, request, uid=None):
        try:
            user= CustomUser.objects.get(uid=uid)
            return user
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Where did i go wrong..

**EDIT :**

I was using if user.is_authenticated before the 'user'. After removing the if condition i am seeing AnonymousUser.

Comment: What do you mean by not available in the template? Is the login working fine?

Comment: @oxalorg i can login but if i go for something like user.username i wont get it.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have the Request context enabled for templates in your settings file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422140/how-to-access-the-user-profile-in-a-django-template

Comment: @oxalorg The django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth inside templates-context-processors? yeah it's there. haven't changed it.